# How do you get an access token to publishing content (Instagram Graph API) client side?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I know I can use this endpoint to get an access token to be able to publish content to a instagram business account:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{graph-api-version}/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app-id}&client_secret={app-secret}&fb_exchange_token={your-access-token}
```

But this method is only server side as you'll need to provide your client_secret.

I'm looking to implement this for a Django project so I need the user to authorize on the client side my facebbok app to publish content to their instagram.

I found this for the Instagram Basic Display:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={instagram-app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}&scope={scope}&response_type=code&state={state}
```

Can this be used for the Instgram Graph API? Do you have an example of this? Because I haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: _"Can this be used for the Instgram Graph API?"_ - no. The Instagram Basic Display API is a separate thing, and doesn't allow for publishing of media to begin with.

Comment: But for the Instagram API, the docs only say that you should implement Facebook login - so you can just use the JS SDK to perform the login client-side. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web